# Preserving backslashes in Perl strings

Tags: perl, backslash, preserve

Is there a way in Perl to preserve and print all backslashes in a string variable?
For example:

```
$str = 'a\\b';
```

The output is

```
a\b
```

but I need

```
a\\b
```

The problem is can't process the string in any way to escape the backslashes because
I have to read complex regular expressions from a database and don't know in which combination and number they appear and have to print them exactly as they are on a web page.

I tried with template toolkit and html and html_entity filters. The only way it works so far is to use a single quoted here document:

```
print <<'XYZ';
a\\b
XYZ
```

But then I can't interpolate variables which makes this solution useless.

I tried to write a string to a web page, into file and on the shell, but no luck, always one backslash disappears. Maybe I am totally on the wrong track, but what is the correct way to print complex regular expressions including backslashes in all combinations and numbers without any changes?

In other words:
I have a database containing hundreds of regular expressions as string data. I want to read them with perl and print them on a web page exatly as they are in the database.
There are all the time changes to these regular expressions by many administrators so I don't know in advance how and what to escape.
A typical example would look like this: 
`'C:\\test\\file \S+'`
but it could change the next day to
`'\S+ C:\\test\\file'`
Maybe a correct conclusion would be to escape every backslash exactly one time no matter in which combination and in which number it appears? This would mean it works to double them up. Then the problem isn't as big as I feared. I tested it on the bash and it works with two and even three backslashes in a row (4 backslaches print 2 ones and 6 backslashes print 3 ones).

Comment: Please give an example of what you want to do. Once backslashes are in a variable they will remain untouched, and will appear correctly if they are interpolated into a string. The only way to put a pair of backslashes into a string *literal* is to double them up, but that shouldn't be a problem. There are several software layers that consider backslash to be an escape character, so your problem may not be within Perl.

Answer (score 3):

The backslash only has significance to Perl when it occurs in Perl source code, e.g.: your assignment of a literal string to a variable:

```
my $str = 'a\\b';
```

However, if you read data from a file (or a database or socket etc) any backslashes in the data you read will be preserved without you needing to take any special steps.

Comment: yes, exactly. Sometimes obvious things take time to understand. Now everything is clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
my $str = 'a\\b';
print $str;
```

This prints `a\\b`.

Use 
my $str = 'a\\\\b';
instead

Comment: No, it prints `a\b`

Comment: Stackoverflow skipped the additional backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

It's a PITA, but you will just have to double up the backslashes, e.g.

```
 a\\\\b
```

Otherwise, you could store the backslash in another variable, and interpolate that.

Answer (score 1):

The minimum to get two slashes is (unfortunately) three slashes:

```
use 5.016;
my $a = 'a\\\b';
say $a;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regular expression to form your string correctly:

```
my $str = 'a\\b';
$str =~ s/\\/\\\\/g;
print "$str\n";
```

This prints `a\\b`.

**EDIT:**

You can use non-interpolating here-document instead:

```
my $str = <<'EOF';
a\\b
EOF
print "$str\n";
```

This still prints `a\\b`.

Comment: Thanks, but works only if you have just doubled backslashes in the string. If you had an additonal single backslash it would be doubled in the output.

Comment: Your `s/\\/\\\\/g` solution does not work on arbitrary regexp strings as pointed out by @Norbert. Your 2nd suggestion however was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I tried to solve does not exist. I confused initializing a string directly in the code with using the html forms. Using a string inside the code preserving all backslashes is only possible either with a here document or by reading a textfile containing the string. But if I just use the html form on a web page to insert a string and use escapeHTML() from the CGI module it takes care of all and you can insert the most wired combinations of special characters. They all get displayed and preserved exactly as inserted. So I should have started directly with html and database operations instead of trying to examine things first
by using strings directly in the code. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Grant's answer provided the hint I needed. Some of the other answers did not match Perl's operation on my system so ...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $var = 'content';

print "\'\"\N{U+0050}\\\\\\$var\n";

print <<END;
\'\"\N{U+0050}\\\\\\$var\n
END

print '\'\"\N{U+0050}\\\\\\$var\n'.$/;

my $str = '\'\"\N{U+0050}\\\\\\$var\n';
print $str.$/;

print @ARGV;
print $/;
```

Called from bash ... using the bash means of escaping in quotes which changes \' to '\''.

```
jamie@debian:~$ ./ft.pl '\'\''\"\N{U+0050}\\\\\\$var\n'
'"P\\\content
'"P\\\content

'\"\N{U+0050}\\\$var\n
'\"\N{U+0050}\\\$var\n
\'\"\N{U+0050}\\\\\\$var\n
```

The final line, with six backslashes in the middle, was what I had expected. Reality differed.

So:

- "in here \" is interpolated
- in HEREDOC \ is interpolated
- 'in single quotes only \' is interpolated and only for \ and ' (are there more?)
- my $str = 'same limited \ interpolation';
- perl.pl 'escape using bash rules' with @ARGV is not interpolated