# How do i use \ (backslash) in a here-doc and have it show up when I print?

Tags: perl, ascii

```
print <<EOTEXT;

      (`-') (`-')  _<-. (`-')_            <-. (`-')  
     _(OO ) ( OO).-/   \( OO) )     .->      \(OO )_ 
,--.(_/,-.\(,------.,--./ ,--/ (`-')----. ,--./  ,-.)
\   \ / (_/ |  .---'|   \ |  | ( OO).-.  '|   `.'   |
 \   /   / (|  '--. |  . '|  |)( _) | |  ||  |'.'|  |
_ \     /_) |  .--' |  |\    |  \|  |)|  ||  |   |  |
\-'\   /    |  `---.|  | \   |   '  '-'  '|  |   |  |
    `-'     `------'`--'  `--'    `-----' `--'   `--'

EOTEXT
```

This is my ascii art that id like to show up in console. How ever it seems that " \ " doesnt show up. Is there a way that i can make it appear.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Preserving backslashes in Perl strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16168763/preserving-backslashes-in-perl-strings)

Comment: @ropra, It does, but there's a better solution for here-docs. As this better solution was mentioned in the linked-*question* (not an answer), this question is obviously not a duplicate of that question. (It would be unsuitable to post the answer to this question as an answer to the linked question.)

Comment: Hi @Juli4N0! You can learn more about this kind of string (called a here-doc) in the perl docs:  https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#%3C%3CEOF

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In double-quoted string literals, `\` is the start of an escape sequence. When followed by a non-word character, it causes that character to be produced. For example, `\|` and `\␠` produce `|` and a space respectively. And of course, `\\` produces `\`, so we can use `\\` where we want `\` in double-quote string literals.

[Here docs](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#%3C%3CEOF) (`<<` string literals) act as double-quoted string literals, unless the token that follows the `<<` is single-quoted. Then the string produced matches the input exactly.

So we have the option of prepending `\` to every special character (`\`, `$` and `@`), or we can simply single-quote the token.

```perl
print <<'EOTEXT';

      (`-') (`-')  _<-. (`-')_            <-. (`-')  
     _(OO ) ( OO).-/   \( OO) )     .->      \(OO )_ 
,--.(_/,-.\(,------.,--./ ,--/ (`-')----. ,--./  ,-.)
\   \ / (_/ |  .---'|   \ |  | ( OO).-.  '|   `.'   |
 \   /   / (|  '--. |  . '|  |)( _) | |  ||  |'.'|  |
_ \     /_) |  .--' |  |\    |  \|  |)|  ||  |   |  |
\-'\   /    |  `---.|  | \   |   '  '-'  '|  |   |  |
    `-'     `------'`--'  `--'    `-----' `--'   `--'

EOTEXT
```